# What do you call the birthday of an organization?

Tags: nouns

I need a noun for the birthday of an organization. Thinking of something like "Declaration Day", "Foundation Day" but none really feel right.

Comment: Naissance is the one word which can be used for birth of an organization.

Comment: No it isn’t. It’s barely even an English word at all, and on the very rare occasion that it is used, it means the birth of a new style or movement within the arts, architecture, philosophy, etc. It is not used for the foundation of an organisation. And it is certainly not used to refer to the _birthday_ of an organisation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right that it does not mean "birthday". But it does mean "a birth, an origination, or a growth, as that of a person, **an organization**, an idea, or a movement." http://www.dictionary.com/browse/naissance

Comment: @NVZ I’d like to see some evidence of that, outside of a lone dictionary definition. I can’t find any recent English sources that use the word in such a sense at all. COCA has only three uses of the word as an English word: two refer to a style in sculpture, one to the birth of a person (in a piece that is generally _very_ high-falutin’ly worded). The OED only has those two definitions as well (the personal one being marked obsolete, the other one rare). Pretty much everything else I can find using the word is in French (including, notably, dictionary.com’s own usage example!).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you're right about all that. I'm not an expert on this. I'm not even a native speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Anniversary"*? *"Incorporation Day"* (if it's an Inc., obviously)?

I think I would just call it, say, *"ELU Day"*. Or maybe *"ELU Anniversary"*.

Comment: I think the Anniversary sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

Founder's Day (or plural, Founders' Day) is sometime used, an allusion to the person or persons who founded the organization, a celebration of the founding.

Comment: Or founding date, or date of establishment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go for something as simple as **Company Birthday**? The meaning is clear, and it's not too complicated.